# convert to unsigned char and unsigned short in Android

Tags: java, android, c, byte

I have to convert my bytes to unsigned char and unsigned short , it is done like this  in iOS

```
latitude = (unsigned char)(bytebuffr.getchar(0)) + ((unsigned short)(bytebuffr.getchar(1)& 0xF)) << 8);
```

How can I achieve this in my android code. please help
already tried this in android but not working,

```
lattitude = (short) ((getUnsignedByte((byte) (bb.getChar(0) & 0xFF))) +
                    getUnsignedByte((byte) ((bb.getChar(1) & 0x0F))) << 8);
```

bb is bytebuffer and bb.getchar is giving me the bytes which is being read from bytebuffer

Comment: What type is `bb`? Please show us the variable declaration, parameter type, or the return type of the method you got it from. What is the return type of `getChar`? (One would hope it's `char`, but... :-) )

Comment: please check the updated question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to convert from `char` to `short` in this case. Since `bb` is a `ByteBuffer`, use [`getShort`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#getShort(int)) if you want to read two bytes from the buffer and use them as a signed 16-bit number. Use [`getChar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#getChar(int)) if you need to read two bytes from the buffer (not one!) and use them as an unsigned 16-bit number. I suspect you're thinking that `getChar` only reads a single byte. It doesn't. `char` is 16 bits wide. Also, `char` is [an unsigned integral type](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se12/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2.1) in Java. Although it's used to represent characters (loosely) in strings, it's an integral (whole number) type. The integral types are:

- `byte`: 8-bit signed: -128 to 127, inclusive
- `short`: 16-bit signed; -32768 to 32767, inclusive
- `char`: 16-bit unsigned: 0 to 65535, inclusive (aka `'\u0000'` to `'\uffff'`)
- `int`: 32-bit signed: -2147483648 to 2147483647, inclusive
- `long`: 32-bit signed: -9223372036854775808 to 9223372036854775807, inclusive

---

If you did need to convert: `char` is an unsigned 16-bit type. `short` is a *signed* 16-bit type. To use the same bits in a `short` as you have in a `char`, you do this:

```
short s = (short)ch;
```

No need for masking off the first byte or anything like that.

Comment: okay got that but then what should be the replacement for unsigned short in java

Comment: @anusaini - `char` is the unsigned equivalent of `short`. People tend to forget that in Java, `char` is an [integral type](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se12/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2.1) like `short` and `int` and `long`. It's not a character type.